# Optimal Hyper-parameter Tuning for Tree Based Models

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, grid-search

I am trying to produce 5 machine learning models and tune them based on a grid search class in order to tune the models in an optimal way so that I am able to use them for predicting new data that will come in everyday. The issue is that the time it takes to do this is way too long. So, my question is what level of parameter tuning is absolutely necessary, but won't take over 2 hours to do? Below is my code for the tuning and classifiers used:

```
#Training and Test Sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = .20, 
random_state = 10)

#Classifiers 
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
randf = RandomForestClassifier()
bag = BaggingClassifier()
gradb = GradientBoostingClassifier()
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
ada = AdaBoostClassifier()

#Hyperparamter Tuning for the Models being used

#Scoring Criteria 
scoring = {'precision': make_scorer(precision_score), 'accuracy': 
make_scorer(accuracy_score)}

#Grid Search for the Decision Tree
param_dtc = {'min_samples_split': np.arange(2, 10), 'min_samples_leaf': 
np.arange(.05, .2), 'max_leaf_nodes': np.arange(2, 30)}
cv_dtc = GridSearchCV(estimator = dtc, param_grid = param_dtc, cv = 3, 
scoring = scoring, refit='precision', n_jobs=-1)
#Grid Search for the Random Forest Model  
param_randf = {'n_estimators': np.arange(10, 20), 'min_samples_split': 
np.arange(2, 10), 'min_samples_leaf': np.arange(.15, .33), 'max_leaf_nodes': 
np.arange(2, 30), 'bootstrap': ['True', 'False']}
cv_randf = GridSearchCV(estimator = randf, param_grid = param_randf, cv = 3, 
scoring = scoring, refit='precision', n_jobs=-1)
#Grid Search for the Bagging Model 
param_bag = {'n_estimators': np.arange(10, 30), 'max_samples': np.arange(2, 
30), 'bootstrap': ['True', 'False'], 'bootstrap_features': ['True', 
'False']}
cv_bag = GridSearchCV(estimator = bag, param_grid = param_bag, cv = 3, 
scoring = scoring, refit='precision', n_jobs=-1)
#Grid Search for the Gradient Boosting Model 
param_gradb = {'loss': ['deviance', 'exponential'], 'learning_rate': 
np.arange(.05, .1), 'max_depth': np.arange(2, 10), 'min_samples_split': 
np.arange(2, 10), 'min_samples_leaf': np.arange(.15, .33), 'max_leaf_nodes': 
np.arange(2, 30)}
cv_gradb = GridSearchCV(estimator = gradb, param_grid = param_gradb, cv = 3, 
scoring = scoring, refit='precision', n_jobs=-1)
#Grid Search for the Adaptive Boosting Model
param_ada = {'n_estimators': np.arange(10, 30), 'learning_rate': 
np.arange(.05, .1)}
cv_ada = GridSearchCV(estimator = ada, param_grid = param_ada, cv = 3, 
scoring = scoring, refit='precision', n_jobs=-1)

train_dict = {'dtc': cv_dtc.fit(x_train, y_train), 'randf': 
cv_randf.fit(x_train, y_train), 'bag': cv_bag.fit(x_train, y_train), 
'gradb': cv_gradb.fit(x_train, y_train), 'ada': cv_ada.fit(x_train, 
y_train)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You might consider some iterative grid search. For example, instead of setting 'n_estimators' to np.arange(10,30), set it to [10,15,20,25,30]. Is the optimal parameter 15, go on with [11,13,15,17,19]. You will find a way to automate this process. This will save a lot of time.
2. Play with your data. You're tuning a lot of hyperparameters. There are intersections of the effects of 'min_samples_split', 'min_samples_leaf' and 'max_leaf_nodes' in the decision tree. Defining all of them might not be necessary.